# Compilation error with lower-bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Consider the following example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
    exceptions.add(new Exception());       // Compile Error
    exceptions.add(new IOException());
    exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException());
}
```

I know that lower-bounded wildcard accepts all classes which are super class of the given class in the wildcard (here **IOException**).

Why does compiler showing compilation error in the above case?

Comment: What if it were an `ArrayList<IOException>`?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> lower-bounded wildcard accepts all classes which are super class of the given class in the wildcard

That refers to the parameterized type, not the types of the objects which may be passed to the methods.  You can assign a `List<Exception>` to that variable, or even a `List<Object>`.

The compiler cannot assume that `exceptions` can hold an `Exception`.  The actual type parameter could be as specific as the lower bound, in this case, `IOException`.  It is legal to assign a `List<IOException>` to `exceptions`, in which case you should not be able to add an `Exception`.  Therefore, the compiler disallows that statement.

If you would like to add an `Exception` and retain a lower bound, change the bound to:

```
List<? super Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

One may of course dispense with the bound entirely:

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Your proposed way of List declaration and what I mentioned in the question is same. I am afraid, did I miss anything?

Comment: *That refers to the type parameter...* I think parameterized type would be more accurate. That is, a type parameterized with a lower bound `T` is a supertype to the same type parameterized with a supertype of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't compile is that the following is legal:

```
List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<IOException>();
```

Then, `exceptions.add(new Exception())` should be disallowed, because an `ArrayList<IOException>` cannot hold an `Exception`.

A solution is to use:

```
// No compiler errors
List<? super Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
exceptions.add(new Exception());
exceptions.add(new IOException());
exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException());
```

Or even:

```
// Also no compiler errors
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
exceptions.add(new Exception());
exceptions.add(new IOException());
exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException());
```

Comment: You are correct. "IOException" can't hold "Exception". But why "Exception" can't hold "Exception"?

Comment: The compiler only cares about what type the list is _declared_ as, in this case `List<? super IOException>`. This could actually refer to a `List<Exception>` or `List<IOException>` and the compiler doesn't know which is true at runtime. So the compiler will only allow things that are OK in both cases. In either case, adding an `IOException` is fine, but adding an `Exception` is wrong in the latter case.